# Show that exist $c\in (a,b)$ such that $cf'(c)+f(c)=0$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives

Suppose $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ is continuous and differentiable in $(a,b)$. Suppose that also 
$$\frac{f(a)}{f(b)}=\frac{b}{a}$$ 
then there exists $c\in(a,b)$ such that $cf'(c)+f(c)=0$.

I have already tried the Mean Value Theorem and combine with hypothesis.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hint:

use the mean value theorem for the function $g(x)=xf(x)$, note that $g'(x) = xf'(x)+f(x)$.

Comment: More specifically, Rolle's Theorem.

Comment: perfect man, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You have $$af(a)=bf(b)$$ thus if you define $$g(x)=xf(x)$$then $g(a)=g(b)$

Also we have $$g'(x)=f(x)+xf'(x)$$

The conditions of Roll's theorem applied to $g(x)$results in $g'(c)=0$ for some $c\in (a,b)$

Thus $g'(c)=f(c)+cf'(c)=0$ for some $c\in (a,b)$